# Git & Android studio : Change the details of submitted change list

Tags: git, android-studio

I'm using git plugin with android studio.
My problem is when I submit a change list(public commit) but my comment in change list was wrong/missing and I want to change it.

**QUESTION :**

Is there any way to edit information of my public committed change list by `git` add on in `AndroidStudio`.

I'm using `MacOSX`.

Answer (score 69):

For Android Studio 3.1.1

1. Click **Version Control** tool window (at the bottom of the window).
2. Click **Log** tab. You will see a list of your commits, with their comments.
3. Right click the commit you want to change its comment, then click **Reword**.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: The real MVP! Thank you!

Comment: simple and useful

Comment: my "Reword" option is disabled, I want to change commit message. conflict resolved commit message.

Comment: In my AS 4.0.1 it's version control->log->right click->Edit Commit Message.. (F2)

Answer (score 9):

You can't change the last commit comment from the editor.
You can amend the last commit, so add an comment to the last commit, but you will also have to commit a change, to do so :

When committing, you have a checkbox `Amend commit`, select it. Your commit will be amend to the previous one.
See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075919/using-intellij-to-amend-git-commit-message)

But if you use the commandline, you might be able to have more options to do what you want, from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/edit-an-incorrect-commit-message-in-git) :

> `git commit --amend`
>
> Will open your editor, allowing you to change the
> commit message of the most recent commit.

Comment: This answer only provides half of the solution. It should also include how to save the new commit message. Always state the "obvious" in your answers. Assume the reader is a dummy, like me in this case.

Comment: @RodrigoMesquita, so how did you save the commit message? I have the same problem as yours lol

Comment: @RodrigoMesquita I see, yeah I used this. Is there any way to save the commit message with Terminal commands instead?

Comment: @Kourosh, yes there is. But the whole point of the new version of Android Studio is to get away from the terminal commands.

Comment: I see, sometimes I prefer old school command line, but better to learn other ways too. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 7):

For Android Version 4.0.1

**Step-1**
Click the Version Control from Bottom of the Android Studio window ***OR*** shortcut key like **Ctrl+9**

[image]

**Step-2**
It opens the Version Control Window

[image]

**Step-3**
Right-click commit message and click the **Edit Commit Message...**
OR Press **F2**

[image]

**Step-4**
It showing **Edit Commit Message** pop-up and you will edit your new commit message and press **OK** button.

[image]

**Step-5**
After that it showing edited commit message in Version Control Log list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio 4.1.1

1. Click Version `Git` (at the bottom of the window).
2. Click `Log all` tab. You will see a list of your commits, with their messages.
3. Right click the commit you want to edit, then click on `Edit Commit Message`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with several wrong commit messages in a row, all of them already pushed.
I followed [Pratik Dodiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9115195/pratik-dodiya) comment and used `Edit Commit Message` on each of the wrong commit messages, then I just did `force push`. Worked like a charm.