# How can I change the textual comment of my last GIT commit using IntelliJ? (I think that is the commit --amend operation)

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ide, git-commit

I am using GIT on IntelliJ and I have the following problem.

I have done a commit with a wrong text message (I have commited it into my staging area but not pushed on the remote repository). I want to change it. I thino that (from command line) I can change the comment of my last commit performing the command:

```
git commit --amend
```

How can I do the same thing by the IntelliJ GIT tool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using IntelliJ to amend git commit message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075919/using-intellij-to-amend-git-commit-message)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the time you ***rebase*** your changes to remote branch.

- ***VCS -> Git -> Rebase***. Check ***Interactive***. Choose your branches and continue.

[image]

- Choose ***reword*** from the drop down forward to your commit. ***Start rebasing***.

[image]

- From the next window, you can ***change your commit message and  resume rebasing***. :))

[image]

Anyway for this kind of things which can be done by simple commands, it is much easier and fast to use the commands.

```
git commit --amend "<new message>"
```

In overall for git, it will be much efficient to use commands rather than tools. :))

Comment: git commit --amend -m "<new message>"